# Knockout value not being set in function

Tags: c#, javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I am having a problem when trying to get self.material (an observable) to load a value from within a function.  When trying to load the observable in the select with a value, it shows as undefined.  data.materialNumber has a string value and self.materials loads correctly.  Any help would be appreciated!

I'll try to include only the code needed...

My html:

```
<select class="materialSelect" data-placeholder="Choose Material..." 
                                data-bind="options: materials,
                            value: material,
                            optionsText: function (item) { return item.description }, 
                            optionsValue: function (item) { return item.materialNumber },
                            chosen: materials,
                            chosenOptions: { width: '250px', search_contains: true }"></select>
```

My js:

```
function Mrs() {

var self = this;


self.materials = ko.observableArray();
self.material = ko.observable("");


bom.hubs.mrs.server()
    .getMaterialsForAuthorizedPlants(lastSection)
    .done(function (data) {
        data.materials.unshift({});
        self.material(data.materialNumber);
        self.materials(data.materials);
    });
 };
(function (bom) {
    "use strict";

    bom.hubs.done(function() {
        ko.applyBindings(new Mrs());
    });

})(bom);
```

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle which shows your issue? It would make it easier to see the issue in action and also to verify that a suggested solution really solves your problem.

Comment: Robert, thanks for reading and commenting.  Next time I submit an issue that can have a fiddle, I'll set one up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR   Assign self.materials before self.material

---

The options binding will attempt to synchronise the selected option with the value, but when you assign self.material there are NO options, so it resets the material value back to undefined.

When you then set self.materials, the options then rebuilds, but self.material is now undefined.

If you swap the assignments, then the select options will be available when the material observable is set.