# KnockoutJS options list value with subscription

Tags: knockout.js

I have a dropdown list inside another list that can have items added to it, and then the user can change the item they added by changing the dropdown list.

This works here, when I add an item the correct value on the dropdown is selected:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
<tr>
    <td>
        <select data-bind="
            options: materials,
            optionsValue: 'MaterialName',
            optionsText: function(item) {
                return item.MaterialGroup + ': ' + item.MaterialName;
            },
            optionsCaption: '[Choose a Material]',
            value : selectedMaterial(),
            attr: { name: 'MaterialOrderLine[' + $index() + '].MaterialName' }"></select> 
    </td>
    ...
```

All of this currently works great.  But now my challenge is I now need to add a subscription to this dropdown to do other things when the selected value of the dropdown changes, which I thought I could do pretty easily, but the subscription here does not work:

```
function MaterialItem(material, qty) {

    var self = this;
    self.materials = ko.observableArray([]);

    //this populates the dropdown lists inside the grid
    $.when(
        $.ajax({
            url: '...',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({... }),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        })
    ).done(function (result) {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            self.materials.push(result[i]);
        }
    });

    self.material = material;
    self.qty = qty;
    self.selectedMaterial =  ko.observable(material); //used to hold selected value on mat'l dropdown

    this.selectedMaterial.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        alert('f');
    }.bind(self));
```

}

This subscription does not work at all.  However, I can get it to work by changing my HTML:
from "value : selectedMaterial()" 
to "value : selectedMaterial"

But when I make that change, the value on the dropdown no longer sets properly (it defaults to the first item on the select list).

Comment: not sure what the `.bind(self)` is for on the end of the subscribe method? haven't seen that before. What happens if you remove that?

Comment: also you assign an observable value like this: `self.material(material);` not like this `self.material = material;`

Comment: I tried it both with and without .bind(self).  That was a suggestion I found on a similar problem, it did not work.

Comment: I think I understand how to assign an observable value, I need to declare it as an observable before I can do something like self.material(material);

Comment: yes they aren't decalred, just add: `self.material = ko.observable(material);` and `self.qty = ko.observable(qty);`

Comment: here's a simple subscription sample I've created for you, just update the name to fire it off: http://jsfiddle.net/kNNvx/1/

Comment: I can get the subscription to work using the example you posted and the one I tried to explain in the original question.  However, my problem is getting the subscription to work AND getting the correct dropdown value displayed.  The subscription works but the dropdown value isnt set with "value : selectedMaterial".  But "value : selectedMaterial()" the subscription breaks however the dropdown value is properly set.

Answer (score 0):

I think is a duplicate of [Knockout value not being set in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682961/knockout-value-not-being-set-in-function)

The option list is being set after the value observable so when the select is bound the selectedMaterial observable has already been reset.

A couple of other things...

- Don't call observableArray's push in a loop, you will cause all bindings to refire each operation.  Either call splice or just set the array value.
- You don't need to use bind(self).  All this does is set the ambient "this" inside the function to reference "self".  You have already captured self in a variable so just us it.

---

```
.done(function (result) {
    self.materials(result);
    self.selectedMaterial(self.material);
}
```